# CxxTest и деструкторы

Tags: c++, юнит-тесты

Допустим есть некоторый класс:

```
class Foo
{
    private:

        double* _data;

    public:

        Foo()
            : _data(new double [512])
        {

        }

       ~Foo()
        {
            delete [] _data;
        }
};
```

Хочу добавить тесты к нему. Как проверить, что деструктор работает и работает адекватно с помощью CxxTest (проверить что правильно работает, а не только, что вызывается)

Comment: Думаю понятно, что на самом деле класс намного более сложен.

Comment: Для этого у Вас должна быть какая-то внешняя (по отношению к Foo) сущность, которая используется в деструкторе Foo и которая переживает деструктор объекта этого класса. Хотя Ваш вопрос несколько необычен: ни разу мне не нужно было тестировать деструктор, это как-то странно.

Comment: Затем, что любая надстройка замедляет работу программы и должна использоваться только тогда, когда это больше необходимо, чем в моём оригинальном проекте.